# Xcode storyboard constraints and auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm working on an app at the moment and one thing that I've been struggling with for the past two weeks has been auto layout. I'm new to iOS programming so I'm not exactly sure the best way to explain my problem but here goes.

I'm making a piano app and the way it works is that my keyboard is just a bunch of buttons laid out next to each other.

[image]

These buttons represent the keys. The buttons have a background image of an image of a regular piano key. Now my problem is that I have a black above the keys and whenever I try to use the pin tool to create constraints for my piano keys, as soon as i add the constraints everything gets pushed up and my keys get stretched vertically.

[image]

[image]

I've been working hours non stop this past week not knowing what's wrong. I've followed manny tutorials but the one's I follow are very basic and at most have a few labels or buttons separated by a ton of space. I'm not sure if it's because my buttons are not spaced out enough or what but it's just extremely frustrated. Any help, or guides/tutorials would be super helpful...

Also I've tried checking the boxes that say to width and height to maintain the width and height however that just makes the keys either too huge or too small on some devices. Is there a way to stretch these keys so they adapt to their device? I've heard of intrinsic size content but don't know how that would apply with over 24 buttons...

Edit:
I tried a stack view but all my white keys got spaced out and went out of the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: For the white buttons -> StackView -> pin to edges all 0's -> put in your 24 buttons inside of the StackView.

Comment: You are showing "squared" black keys at the top, but then "rounded" black keys in the lower image... Can you show your actual button images?

Comment: Added a new picture @DonMag

Comment: @J.Doe I tried making a stack view with black and white keys but noticed spacing because of the black keys..So with a stack view of just white keys I should just overlay the black keys on top and pin them inside the stack view?

Comment: My suggestion would be: don't use buttons for the keys. Use views. Now you can say what the size should be. Also, what are your goals here? What's the purpose of using auto layout? In other words, what is it that you want to have happen on different screen sizes?

Comment: @matt I'll attempt to use views. I was thinking about using auto layout just so the keys grow in proportion to screen size. I want them to look the same on every device. I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Keys grow how??? If you can't be specific, you can't possibly design constraints. You must be able to say very clearly what you want regardless of screen size. Do you want your two octaves of keys to fill the landscape screen in both dimensions? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @matt I'm sorry I should've been more specific, my bad. Yes i want both octave keys to fill the landscape regardless of screen size. I also want the height to be the same height on every screen size so like 200 points in height. I'm not sure how more specific to be as I don't know enough about constraints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons will be easier to use than views when it comes to triggering actions so stick with buttons. We will constrain their sizes so they behave.

Start by getting rid of the black keys until the white keys are all set.

Pin all of the white keys to the top and bottom of the screen.

Set them all to have the same width.

Pin the first key to the leading edge and the last key to the trailing edge of the superview.

Select all the white keys *except* the last one and pin the right side with the spacing at 0.

That should make it so that all the white keys fill the screen with no space around the edges or between them.

Use the assistant editor in the storyboard and select preview from it. Add a few different screen sizes and turn them to landscape. It may not look exactly the way it will on a device but it should be pretty close.

Once the white keys look right add the black keys into the mix.

Start with just one black key and drag to resize it to the proper size in the storyboard. Once you have that size right add an aspect ratio constraint so you only have to worry about adjusting the width and not the height.

Temporarily set the label of the black key to "b" or some other single character, we will need it later.

You will need to do a tiny bit of math to get the black key to be the right width on all screens… Select the black key and look in the size inspector for it width, do the same for the superview. Once you have those numbers divide the black key width by the superview width. make note of the result as you will need it in a moment.

Now that you know the percentage of the screen width the black key takes up select the black key and the superview. Set them to have the same width. (This may make the black key get crazy big, we will fix that in a moment)

Select just the black key, go to the size inspector, and double click on the constraint that makes its width match the superview.

That will select the constraint itself. In its attributes set the multiplier to be the same as the decimal number you got by dividing the black key width by the screen width.

That takes care of the size of the black keys, now to deal with positioning them.

First duplicate the black key you have created until you have all that you need.

Select all the black keys and pin them to the top of the superview.

Manually drag all the black keys into the right places (you don't need to be precise just in the right area).

The final bit of alignment we need to do is to make it so that the center of each black key is over the line between white keys…

Select a black key and either control or right click and drag from it to the white key on its right side. Select horizontal spacing from the menu that appears.

In the size inspector double click on that new constraint (it should have a negative number).

In the attributes for the constraint you should see that it has a first item and second item. One of those items is "b" (or whatever label you used for the black key earlier). If you click on the popup menu you should see trailing is checked. Select Center X instead. Finally set the constant to 0.

That should lock that black key into the proper size and place. Now repeat the process for the rest of the black keys.

Once that is done you can get rid of the labels and make sure all the images are properly set.

It isn't a quick process but it gets easier over time.

If the white keys end up with space on some screens try making sure they are set to scale to fill (hopefully that doesn't mess up the bottom curves too much).

Comment: I managed to do the white keys, thank you but how do I set the width of the black key and the superview to be the same?

Comment: Omg ok so that pretty much worked, at least for one black key. However it doesn't work for iPads 10.5 and 12.9...It does work for iPad 9.7 and the rest of the iPhone devices. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks again that fix worked so good!

Comment: If the issue on those larger screens is sizing of the black keys I would kill the aspect ratio and width constraint on all but one of the black keys and add constraints to make all of them same width and same height. Then you could adjust the constants for one width and one height constraint in `viewDidLoad` on screen sizes that don't work right now.

Comment: Ok so I removed all with constraints and aspect ratios from the black keys and it was fine but still freaking out whenever i switched to bigger iPads. I'm going to attempt the viewDidLoad constraint thing but for what button do I set the constraints? for all of them? Would I have to do an NSLayoutConstraint for each black key? By the way, thank you so much for helping me out thus far. As someone starting out with iOS it means a ton!

Comment: I forgot to be a bit more specific. The black keys get pushed above the white keys on iPads 10.5 and 12.9. I'm guessing I would have to make an NSLayoutConstraint for iPad in viewdidload and an if statement to recognize if the app is running on an iPad? I'm still not sure what my constant would be because on the smallest iPad the black keys are positioned correctly so my assumption is that modifying the constant would have to be different for every iPad..

Comment: If you set all the black keys to have the same width and height adjusting one will affect them all. Easiest way is to add an outlet for the width and height constraints of one black key and set the constant as needed in `viewDidLoad`. You might want to use the view debugger or set the background color of the white keys to something noticeable. maybe the white keys are filling the screen properly but the image isn't filling the height (anything other than scale to fill would leave part of the button with no image).

Comment: What I ended up doing was just stretching the vertical alignment of the image inside the button in order to fill the parts of the button that has no image. This pretty much solved the issue except I can't align the title properly anymore even with the insets. I think I'll just use labels for the text inside the button.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 11 you can give the layer of each white button a border and round the bottom corners, might give you what you are looking for. `let layer = someButton.layer` to get the layer. Masking the right corners is a bit verbose `layer.maskedCorners =  CACornerMask(rawValue: CACornerMask.layerMinXMaxYCorner.rawValue | CACornerMask.layerMaxXMaxYCorner.rawValue)`

Comment: Yea I tried that and it looked okay but do you know if it's possible to make a black box behind the text like in the first picture of my question? I had in mind that maybe making a frame and placing it behind the text. Another work around that I currently have instead of having the image said as "Image" in it's attributes inspector, I set it to "Background Image" and then just vertically made the text in the bottom however on iPad the text is smaller and pushed further down so Im might just modify it in viewDidLoad. I'm welcome to suggestions though.

Comment: You could try setting the background color and corner radius of a text label. Maybe create a custom subclass of `UIButton` for each key color. Then you could use constraints from code to put the label exactly where you want it and if needed add a backing view to create the colored circle.

Comment: I'll give it a try, why is it that when I try to constrain a label by pinning to all four sides inside the white key that on different devices it just moves to a completely different spot. Is it because there's not enough defined constraints? I also tried just making the UIbutton into a white key and made my text into attributed text and set a background but I can't make the background rounded, from your experience do you know if that is possible? Also to set the width and height of it?

Comment: If you want it to stick near the bottom of the key don't do a top constraint. If Xcode complains turn up the vertical content hugging priority on the label. You should be able to round the corners of anything that inherits from `UIView` by grabbing its layer and setting the `cornerRadius`. I've never tried `UILabel` though. If it can't be rounded put an extra view behind the label that has rounded corners and the right color. If you lock their horizontal and vertical centers together the user will never know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I abandoned the idea of putting text there. I'm having a huge problem though. I want to add another button above the piano keys but I'm getting conflicted constraints for some reason. https://imgur.com/51DlrDN

Comment: If you constants for width, leading, and trailing that are all equal to you will always have conflicts on all the other screen sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I would do. Let's ignore the black bar at the top for a moment and concentrate solely on the keys. And for a moment let's ignore the black keys. So let's imagine we have 14 white key views, and they are to fill the screen regardless of its size.

That's easy. Start with one white key view. Pin it to the top, left, and bottom of the superview, and set its width arbitrarily to, say, 10. Now just keep adding white key views with their left pinned to the right of the previous view, their top and bottom pinned to the superview, and their width set *equal to the first view's width*. Finally, pin the 14th key view's right to the right of the superview.

At that point, of course, Interface Builder will balk, because the widths do not all add up to make it possible to pin the leftmost key to the left and the rightmost key to the right. But now you remove the width constraints on the first key! Presto, the keys adjust themselves to fill the total width of the screen.

Here's the result in Interface Builder on my screen. I've allowed a little extra space and I've colored the white keys green for clarity. I created an IBDesignable custom UIView subclass so as to simulate the roundy shape of the bottom end of the keys.

[image]

The black keys are similar except that you will need three invisible "spacer" black keys to dictate the gaps in the series. Here's my Interface Builder with the black keys added:

[image]

Here's the app running on the iPad simulator:

[image]

Here it is running on the iPhone 5s simulator:

[image]

That shows, I think, that this is a viable strategy. It's just a matter of minor tweaks from this point to get the exact look you want.

Comment: Ok, all of what you said makes perfect sense and I can see it working especially the spacing with the black keys. I'm just wondering difference does working with different views, I'm assuming the "view" object from interface builder right, have with buttons? Aren't constraints the same regardless of object? I'll give this a try though!

Comment: The problem with buttons is that they are self-sizing under auto layout. I recommend that you use custom UIViews so that you are in complete control of the size and the drawing.

Comment: Added black keys along with screen shots on different devices to show that we are doing what you asked for.