# Retrieving/setting values of UIView Objects in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, function, uiview, swift4

I have a `UIView` class called Keyboard in my ViewController to create customizable piano keyboard diagrams:

```
class Key: UIView {
    var keyType = 0
    var keyTypeArray = ["A", "Bb", "B", "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab"]
    // error key type: 0
    // white key types: 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11
    // black key types: 2, 5, 7, 10, 12

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect())
        self.backgroundColor = .white

        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 62.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}



   class Keyboard: UIView {
        let initialKey: Int
        let numberOfKeys: Int
        var scale: Double

        var keys = [Key]()
        var numWhiteKeys = 0
        var numBlackKeys = 0
        var startingX: CGFloat = 100.0
        var startingY: CGFloat = 200.0
        var zPos: CGFloat

        var keyboardDimensions = [23.0, 24.0, 14.0, 91.0, 52.0]
        //        narrowWhiteKeyWidth = 23.0
        //        wideWhiteKeyWidth = 24.0
        //        blackKeyWidth = 14.0
        //        whiteKeyHeight = 91.0
        //        blackKeyHeight = 52.0

        var blackOffsetsArray = [20.0, 38.0, 14.0, 19.0, 36.0, 13.0, 17.0]
        var whiteOffsetsArray = [3.0, 9.0, 5.0, 11.0, 7.0]
        var nextBlackKeyPos = [41.0, 28.0, 41.0, 27.0, 27.0]

        init(startingX: CGFloat, startingY: CGFloat, initialKey: Int, numberOfKeys: Int, scale: Double, zPos: CGFloat) {
            self.startingX = startingX
            self.startingY = startingY
            self.initialKey = initialKey
            self.numberOfKeys = numberOfKeys
            self.scale = scale
            self.zPos = zPos
            super.init(frame: CGRect())
        }

        @discardableResult
        func addKeys() -> [UIView] {
            for (index, _) in blackOffsetsArray.enumerated() {
                blackOffsetsArray[index] *= scale
            }
            for (index, _) in whiteOffsetsArray.enumerated() {
                whiteOffsetsArray[index] *= scale
            }
            for (index, _) in nextBlackKeyPos.enumerated() {
                nextBlackKeyPos[index] *= scale
            }
            for (index, _) in keyboardDimensions.enumerated() {
                keyboardDimensions[index] *= scale
            }

            var counter = initialKey
            var whiteKeys = [Key]()
            var blackKeys = [Key]()
            var wXPos = CGFloat()
            var bXPos = CGFloat()

            let blackOffsetsDict = [1: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 6: 3, 8: 4, 9: 5, 11: 6]
            let whiteOffsetsDict = [2: 0, 5: 1, 7: 2, 10: 3, 12: 4]

            switch  initialKey {
            case 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11:
                wXPos = startingX
                if let offsetNum = blackOffsetsDict[initialKey] {
                    bXPos = startingX + CGFloat(blackOffsetsArray[offsetNum])
                }
            case 2, 5, 7, 10, 12:
                bXPos = startingX
                if let offsetNum = whiteOffsetsDict[initialKey] {
                    wXPos = startingX + CGFloat(whiteOffsetsArray[offsetNum])
                }
            default:
                print("Error!")
            }

            while counter <= (numberOfKeys + initialKey - 1)   {
                var keyNum = Int()
                let timesIn = Int(counter/12)
                let key = Key()

                key.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5*CGFloat(scale), height: 5*CGFloat(scale))
                key.layer.shadowRadius = 5*CGFloat(scale)

                if counter <= 12 {
                    keyNum = counter
                } else if counter > 12 && (counter % 12) != 0 {
                    keyNum = counter - (12 * (timesIn))
                } else {
                    keyNum = counter - (12 * (timesIn - 1))
                }

                switch keyNum {
                case 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11:
                    keys.append(key)
                    whiteKeys.append(key)
                    self.numWhiteKeys += 1
                    key.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    key.layer.cornerRadius = 5*CGFloat(scale)
                    key.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                    key.layer.zPosition = zPos
//                    print("keyNum is \(keyNum), counter is \(counter)")

                    switch keyNum {
                    case 1, 4, 8, 11:
                        key.frame = CGRect(x: Double(wXPos), y: Double(startingY), width: keyboardDimensions[0], height: keyboardDimensions[3])

                        switch keyNum {
                        case 1:
//                            print("  A")
                            key.keyType = 1
                        case 4:
//                            print("  C")
                            key.keyType = 4
                        case 8:
//                            print("  E")
                            key.keyType = 8
                        case 11:
//                            print("  G")
                            key.keyType = 11
                        default:
                            key.keyType = 0
                            print("  Error!")
                        }
                    case 3, 6, 9:
                        key.frame = CGRect(x: Double(wXPos), y: Double(startingY), width: keyboardDimensions[1], height: keyboardDimensions[3])

                        switch keyNum {
                        case 3:
//                            print("  B")
                            key.keyType = 3
                        case 6:
//                            print("  D")
                            key.keyType = 6
                        case 9:
//                            print("  F")
                            key.keyType = 9
                        default:
                            key.keyType = 0
                            print("  Error!")
                        }
                    default:
                        key.keyType = 0
                        print("  Error!")
                    }

                    wXPos += key.frame.width

                case 2, 5, 7, 10, 12:
                    self.numBlackKeys += 1
                    key.layer.zPosition = zPos + 1
                    key.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5*CGFloat(scale)
                    key.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                    key.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                    key.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2*CGFloat(scale), height: 2*CGFloat(scale))
                    key.layer.shadowRadius = 2*CGFloat(scale)
                    key.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
//                    print("keyNum is \(keyNum), counter is \(counter)")

                    key.frame = CGRect(x: Double(bXPos), y: Double(startingY), width: keyboardDimensions[2], height: keyboardDimensions[4])

                    switch keyNum {
                    case 2:
//                        print("  Bb")
                        key.keyType = 2
                        bXPos += CGFloat(nextBlackKeyPos[0])
                    case 5:
//                        print("  Db")
                        key.keyType = 5
                        bXPos += CGFloat(nextBlackKeyPos[1])
                    case 7:
//                        print("  Eb")
                        key.keyType = 7
                        bXPos += CGFloat(nextBlackKeyPos[2])
                    case 10:
//                        print("  Gb")
                        key.keyType = 10
                        bXPos += CGFloat(nextBlackKeyPos[3])
                    case 12:
//                        print("  Ab")
                        key.keyType = 12
                        bXPos += CGFloat(nextBlackKeyPos[4])
                    default:
                        key.keyType = 0
                        print("  Error!")
                    }

                    keys.append(key)
                    blackKeys.append(key)
                default:
                    key.keyType = 0
                    print("Key # is \(keyNum). Error!")
                }
                counter += 1
            }

            return keys
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

And then I have an `addKeyboard` function that creates each keyboard and adds it to a `keyboards` array:

```
var keyboards = [Keyboard]()

    func addKeyboard(startingX: CGFloat, startingY: CGFloat, initialKey: Int, numberOfKeys: Int, scale: Double, zPos: CGFloat) {

        let myKeyboard = Keyboard(startingX: startingX, startingY: startingY, initialKey: initialKey, numberOfKeys: numberOfKeys, scale: scale, zPos: zPos)
        myKeyboard.addKeys()
        myKeyboard.layer.zPosition = zPos
        var i = 0
        while i < myKeyboard.keys.count {
            view.addSubview(myKeyboard.keys[i])
            i += 1
        }
        keyboards.append(myKeyboard)
    }
```

Finally, in viewDidLoad, I can call addKeyboard like so:

```
addKeyboard(startingX: 250, startingY: 30, initialKey: 9, numberOfKeys: 7, scale: 1.0, zPos: 2)
addKeyboard(startingX: 150, startingY: 100, initialKey: 4, numberOfKeys: 5, scale: 0.5, zPos: 2)
```

etc. (5 more keyboards)
[image]

My problem is when I retrieve my keyboards array and try to change any of the keyboards' values. The array returns a bunch of UIViews with frames of (0 0; 0  0), and I can't change any parameters from viewDidLoad.

This:

```
print(keyboards)
keyboards[5].scale = 2.0
print(keyboards[5].scale)
print(keyboards[5].frame)
```

yields this:

```
[<_TtCC17drawKeyboardTest314ViewController8Keyboard: 0x7f9f9b2002e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60400003f4c0>>, <_TtCC17drawKeyboardTest314ViewController8Keyboard: 0x7f9f9b105390; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002225c0>>
```

etc.

and the `print(keyboards[5].scale)` yields 2.0 but the actual size doesn't change (results of last 2 `print()` calls above).

```
2.0
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

How do I change things so that I after I add my Keyboards to the keyboards array, I can then get the proper values and change them as needed (for example, resize, move around, highlight certain keys)?

Thanks so much.

Jake

Comment: You have a property: `var scale: Double` ... but I don't see any code that is going to do anything when you change that value?

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. I didn't include all of the Keyboard or Key classes because I thought it would be too much but I definitely left out some of the important stuff! I edited to include everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues...

1. You are defining a `class Keyboard: UIView`, and within that class you are creating (and setting frames for) a bunch of `class Key: UIView`.

However, you are adding those `Keys` as subviews of the *main* view of your ViewController, when you should be adding them as subviews of the `Keyboard` view. You would then add the `keyboard` to your main `.view`. (Note: you'll also need to set the frame of the keyboard object to contain its keys).

2. Your code is not doing anything when you change the `.scale` property.

One option is to add a "resize()" type function, and either call that directly, or call it automatically when you change the scale property. Perhaps like so:

```
var scale: Double {
    didSet {
        self.resize()
    }
}
```

As a side note, you will likely get better results - and I expect it will be easier in the long run - to use auto-sizing and constraints rather than explicit positions and sizes for the "keys".

Comment: Oh wow. I completely failed to realize that at no point in my code do I set the frame of my `Keyboards`—only the `Keys`. I even had to do a search for `Keyboard.frame` (came up with 0 matches naturally) to confirm. Of course the Keyboards array returns Keyboards with frames of 0 0 0 0, I never set them!

Thank you for helping me see that.

So do I say `myKeyboard.addSubView(myKeyboard.keys[i]` instead of `view.addSubview(myKeyboard.keys[i]`)?

And then do I need to calculate the total width and height of all my Keys and set the Keyboard frame to that?

Comment: Thanks also for the tip about the "resize()" function, I think I can probably implement that pretty easily. I don't have much experience with auto-sizing and constraints (I'm not even sure how they would apply), so I may have to try that later after reading up. What would be a good place to start? Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084297/6257435 ... It shows how to layout a piano keyboard in Interface Builder, but implementing it in code would be a pretty simple task. It's using auto-layout, which would also make it much easier to implement a "scale" factor.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I'll explore it more and see if I can understand how to apply it. It took some doing but I managed to write the resize() function and get it to work. I also updated the addKeyboard function to add the Keyboard to my main view, set the frame for my Keyboard, and add the Keys as subviews of my main view. I can now add, move, resize and change the opacity and other parameters of my Keyboards in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Just to clarify: does the Keyboard frame need to be the same width and height as the height and combined width of the Keys? It seems to work without doing that but should I do it anyway?

Comment: Set a background color on your Keyboard view... That will show you if the frame is sized how you want it.

Comment: Thanks! I did as you suggested and I'm glad I did—the frame was not only the wrong size (which I knew already because I hadn't calculated it according the keys' dimensions), but also completely offset from the area the keys were in! I was able to fix it so now everything's lined up. And now to see about auto-layout and constraints...